# Qt and high dpi screens

Tags: qt

I've read several articles on this.  So I have a Dell XPS 13 and changed the size of text, apps and other items to 200%

[image]

But I guess my question is the following.  When I launch the application through Qt Designer everything looks good:

[image]

[image]

But when I run the application outside of the Designer( meaning just double clicking the application to run it), the size is different:

[image]

[image]
This toolbar is actually smaller than what the screenshot shows.  So my question is there a setting I can set my application so when I launch it outside of the Designer it will look like when it was launched from the Designer?

Comment: Which version are you on? I ask because the 5.6 beta is supposed to address some of these high DPI issues.

Comment: Version 5.5.1.  Is there a workaround pre 5.6?

Answer (score 1):

For certain widget classes you can try to provide size measures relative to its font size with the stylesheet:

```
pMyWidget->setStyleSheet(
   "MyWidget {"            // What type is it? 
       "min-width: 80em;"  // If the dimension
       "min-height: 40em;" // attribute is
       "width: 160em;"     // applicable
       "height: 80em;"     // to this type.
       // margin:          // See the list
       // padding:         // of related
       // spacing:         // attributes
"}");
```

That "`em`" refers to capital "M" font size AFAIR. *The tricky part here is what actual MyWidget type is and if you can apply a stylesheet like that.* You can probably omit the widget type in style `MyWidget {}` but leave the contents yet it supposed to modify all the widgets that that one is parenting.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm wondering though does the Designer do something when it launches the application for it to look different than when launched manually?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe if more that one monitor in the system than the one that the app starts on is reflected on default scaling.

Comment: I guess my question is how does the Designer do it when I launch the application after I do a build?  Im doing it on my Dell XPS13 notebook on both running on the designer and not and I notice the difference

Comment: May be you can find a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714837/how-to-get-sharp-ui-on-high-dpi-with-qt-5-6/60597567#60597567