# Qt Application becomes larger than screen if QDockWidget becomes visible

Tags: c++, qt, dpi, mxe

I have old `Qt` `C++` Application which works perfectly in Desktop or Laptop. I am now trying to make it work in a `High DPI` touchscreen embedded device having `10 inch` screen having 1920 X 1200 Resolution. The device is running `Windows 10`. I am using `MXE` to cross-compile for Windows in my Ubuntu machine.

Following the suggestion given over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714837/how-to-get-sharp-ui-on-high-dpi-with-qt-5-6), I added following lines to automatically scale my application.

```
static const char ENV_VAR_QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO[] = "QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO";
if (!qEnvironmentVariableIsSet(ENV_VAR_QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO)
    && !qEnvironmentVariableIsSet("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR")
    && !qEnvironmentVariableIsSet("QT_SCALE_FACTOR")
    && !qEnvironmentVariableIsSet("QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS")) {
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
}
```

The application starts with right size:

[image]

However, when I make `settingWidget` visible which is added to `QDockWidget`, then the application becomes larger than the screen size. I am unable to understand the source of problem.

[image]

The codebase is very large if someone wants to review the code then they have to help me with the code fragment which may have the bug and I will shall post it here.

Comment: I am using MXE to cross compile for Wndows system on my Ubuntu Laptop. The version is 5.13

Comment: Just try restore main window size and state before show() or call show() before restoring.